# How to configure distributed Topic or Queue using Apache MQ with JNDI properties and also embeded MQ in applicaiton server

Tags: apache, jms, activemq-classic

We are moving from weblogic jms to activemq. We put all the activemq required jar files into our application classpath and created one properties file which contains activemq url and connectionfactory details like below:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616

connectionFactoryNames=TestTopicConnectionFactory

topic.mq/TestTopic=TestTopic

During server startup we are loading this properties file as below and starting the MQ broker srevice.

public TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private MQStartup mqStartup = null;
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config)
            throws ServletException {
            super.init(config);
            mqStartup = new MQStartup();
            mqStartup.startBrokerService();
    }
}
public class MQStartup {
    private final String bindAddress;
    private BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();

    public MQStartup(){
        MQContext context = new MQContext();
        context.loadJndiProperties();
        bindAddress = ActiveMQContext.getProperty("java.naming.provider.url");
    }

    public void startBrokerService() {
        broker.addConnector(bindAddress);
        broker.start();
    }

    public void stopBrokerService() {
        try {
            broker.stop();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to stop the MQ Broker service " +e);
        }
    }
}


public class MQContext {
    private static final Object singletonLock = new Object();
    static Context context = null;
    static Properties properties = null;
    private boolean loaded = false;

    public void loadJndiProperties() {
        try {
            if (!loaded) {
                synchronized (singletonLock) {
                    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("jda-activemq-jndi.properties");
                    properties = new Properties();
                    properties.load(url.openStream());
                    context = new InitialContext(properties);
                    loaded = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | NamingException ie) {
            logger.error("Failed to load apachemq jndi", ie);
        }
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public static Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public static String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

In implementation class for producing message we are getting the mq connectionfactory lile below:

```
TopicConnectionFactory factory = (TopicConnectionFactory) MQContext.getContext().lookup("<topicFactoryName>");

this.topicConnection = factory.createTopicConnection();
this.topicConnection.start();
```

and then creating topic session and using publisher.publish("message");

But the problem here is we have 3 application instance in cluster and for these 3 instance we have 3 embeded activemq broker service.

When I am producing one message and sending in instance1(suppose webserver is hitting instance1) this message is not consumed by other2 instance.

I googled there is some networkconnector configuration can be helped. But the problem is we are using JNDI and MQ is not a separate installation.

Is there any way to do this with embeded MQ and with JNDI.

**Note:** In weblogic we have ***UniformDistributedTopic*** type of topic which helps to achive the above but in MQ it seems we don't have this kind of topic type.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want the three embedded instance of ActiveMQ to form a network of brokers (http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html).  Are you configuring your embedded broker instances to form a network of brokers?  All your local clients should still be able to connect to the embedded instance using JNDI, but messages can be shared across the network of brokers.

Comment: Hi @Gary. I am new to activemq. We have two consumer one is to insert/update data to db and other one is to fetch the data from db and cached it.

Comment: 1. We want to use jndi properties file to get the connections, topics etc. I have not configured it as network broker.
    Is it possible to configure network broker using jndi properties file or programatically? If network broker is configured then the consumer which is doing insert/update, will it insert/update two times if we have two instance(duplicate concern). We want only the second consumer which is doing fetch data and cached it across the instance should be distributed not all consumer.
2. I uploaded a sample into git for the reference.(https://github.com/AratRana/ApacheActiveMQ)

Comment: JNDI has nothing to do with configuring a network of brokers. You should be able to configure it programmatically. If you're sending your message to a queue then you'll get queue semantics even in a network of brokers. In other words, the message will only be consumed once regardless of the number of consumers.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram. I am completely new to the apache activemq, we have the configured the tcp url for mq in jndi properties file. I am not sure how to write network connector programatically not using any xml file.

The business use case we have insert/update, select query which will be called by the jms and for the select (fetch data from db and cache it) will be consumed by othe instance consumer other than the instance which is producing.

Comment: For e.g I have 3 applicaiton server instance instance1,2 and 3 and suppose instance1 produce the message then it should be consumed by instance2 and instance3 not by instance1 which subscribed to the jms topic. For the insert/update it will be consumed once only in any of the instance 

Is there any way to do this using network connector programatically?

Comment: One more point is we have embeded the mq broker service per instance

Comment: As noted previously, your embedded brokers should be configured to form a network of brokers so messages produced on one broker can be consumed on another broker on the network.